# Loading XML data into MySQL 5.0

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xml-parsing

The sheer lack of suitable solutions here is driving me crazy.

A customer has given me an XML file that is 14MB in size and may be bigger in future requests. I need a script that can periodically load its data into a MySQL table. The server is running MySQL 5.0.96, so I don't believe the LOAD XML command is available to me.

I have tried using the PHP DOM lib to parse the XML file, but Apache returns 500 internal server error. I believe this to be a memory shortage because I can comment out the PHP code loading the XML file and the script runs smoothly (with no data). The memory limit on the server is already 128MB.

I have tried XMLReader as well and it seems to do the same thing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, xmlreader is probably a good way to go, but what is your question exactly?

Comment: Server returns 500 internal server error due to memory limit when I attempt to load this XML file using Dom Lib or XMLReader. Are there any better ways of getting the XML into the table with PHP?

Comment: did you try python? its pretty easy to do such thing using python

Comment: The platform our customer is using is PHP. I am in no position to suggest we switch to python at this time.

Comment: XMLReader works as iterators so unlike the dom or simplexml parser it won't have to load the full xml file into memory. Can you show some example of the xml file so we could see how the xml elements -> sql rows should be generated?

Comment: I have loaded Gigs of XML into MySQL using XMLReader and have never hit any issues with memory. What I found is that the individual nodes within the XML is usually pretty small so I do a read() to jump between nodes, convert them to SimpleXML objects by loading the raw XML for the node into the SimpleXMLElement constructor, and then I just access all of the data easily. Keeps the code as simple as possible.

Comment: I may have been mistaken about XMLReader doing the same thing. Can you provide me with a sample of how you use it that way? I have found samples on other posts, but they didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

XMLReader works as an iterator, so you will have to implement your grouping / extracting logic in terms of individual tokens of the xml document. Assuming that there's an element like `<row>` in your xml file that corresponds to a single insert it could look something like this:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('/path/to/the/file.xml');
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->name == "row" && $reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        // the cursor currently at <row> element

        // hopefully one fragment will fit into memory and you can use simplexml for easy access
        // alternatively try $reader->expand() for DOMNode of the same thing
        $rowxml = simplexml_load_string('<'.'?xml version='1.0'?'.'>'.$reader->readOuterXML());

        // build insert from the $rowxml object, run the query
    }
}
$reader->close();
```